# How to make ENTER do something and ENTER+SHIFT do something else at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, keydown

I am having a `textarea` in which when you press Enter alone a jquery ajax get fired up but i want to add the feature which is when you press Enter + Shift to only go to new line and not fire up the ajax. Can you guide me please with that ?

here is the code that i've written so far in jquery but when i click Shift+Enter the ajax gets fired as well, i need to eliminate that

```js
$('.inbox_message_textarea').keydown(function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
    console.log("You pressed Enter Key alone");
  }
  if( code == 13 && e.shiftKey ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("You pressed SHIFT+ENTER");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="inbox_message_textarea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> press and then check <kbd>Enter</kbd> press. Also use `else if` instead of second `if`

```js
$('.inbox_message_textarea').keydown(function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code == 13 && e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("You pressed SHIFT+ENTER");
  } else if (code == 13) { 
    console.log("You pressed Enter Key alone");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="inbox_message_textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Seems we offered up the exact same solution, I'll delete mine.

Comment: Thank you that worked ! I tried it before and it did not but when i flipped between the if it worked perfectly ! Can you please explain why should the ifs be flipped ?

Comment: firasprogrammer - you should accept the given solution and maybe upvote Mohammad for helping you solve your issue.

Comment: i upvoted him but can't accept the solution before 5 min